# SQL query using two or more tables

Tags: php, sql, select, inner-join

I am trying to get information from my SQL into PHP page, the problem I have I am trying to use multiple tables to populate the result

Table's columns are same names though but table names obviously differs.

Table ticket

status_id; 
ticket_id

Table ticket__cdata

ticket_id

```
 SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE status_id = '1' ORDER BY created DESC
```

I filter the table only looking for 1 in TABLE A

I echo the TICKET_ID on the php from Table A but now I want to filter in Table B the ticket_id and pull information from that form. Table be does not have status_id in it so cannot filter on that again.

Logic says I must say something like this

```
 SELECT * FROM ticket_cdata WHERE ticket_id = '".$ticket_id."'
```

Here is my code to date without the second query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ost_ticket WHERE status_id = '1' ORDER   
BY created DESC");
?>
      <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
      <tr>
        <td class="center">
          <div align="center"><? echo $rows['number']; ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><? echo $rows['ticket_id']; ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><? echo $rows['lbs_time']; ?></div></td> //This it the info required from TABLE ticket but must be linked to the status_id
```

UPDATED STRING

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT   tc.* 
FROM     ticket_cdata tc
JOIN     ticket t ON tc.ticket_id = t.ticket_id 
WHERE    t.status_id = '1' 
ORDER BY t.created DESC");
?>


      <tr>
        <td class="center">
          <div align="center"><? echo $rows['number']; ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><? echo $rows['ticket_id']; ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><? echo $rows['created']; ?></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><? echo $rows['subject']; ?></div></td>
```

Now I cannot Echo any info

Answer (score 2):

You could use a join:

```
SELECT   tc.* 
FROM     ticket_cdata tc
JOIN     ticket t ON tc.ticket_id = t.ticket_id 
WHERE    t.status_id = '1' 
ORDER BY t.created DESC
```

Comment: I have done it like you described but now when I echo the info nothing is shown

Answer (score 0):

Your initial query can be changed to this:

```
SELECT * FROM ticket t
WHERE t.status_id = '1' 
   AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ticket__cdata WHERE ticket_id = t.ticket_id)
ORDER BY t.created DESC
```

This limits results to tickets that are present in `ticket__cdata` table and have `status_id = '1'`.